# How to get the option text using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I want to using BeautifulSoup to get the option text in the following html. For example: I'd like to get 2002/12 , 2003/12 etc.

```
<select id="start_dateid">
<option value="0">2002/12</option>
<option value="1">2003/12</option>
<option value="2">2004/12</option>
<option value="3">2005/12</option>
<option value="4">2006/12</option>
<option value="5" selected="">2007/12</option>
<option value="6">2008/12</option>
<option value="7">2009/12</option>
<option value="8">2010/12</option>
<option value="9">2011/12</option>
</select>
```

What's the best way to get the contents? Now I'm using the following code but I don't know how to use beautiful soup for that. If there are more than one selected areas in the html file, the result will be incorrect. Here is what I have so far:

```
    import urllib2
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import lxml

    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("./test.html").read(),"lxml");
    for item in soup.find_all('option'):
            print(''.join(str(item.find(text=True))));
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't have to use `lxml` here.  I have trouble installing it on my machine, so my answer does not make use of it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import urllib2

soup = BS(urllib2.urlopen("./test.html").read())
contents = [str(x.text) for x in soup.find(id="start_dateid").find_all('option')]
```

With this, you avoid the issue of multiple select areas in the html file, since we're first limiting by `id='start_dateid'`, which guarantees for you that you have the right `<select>`, since within each html document each html element must have a unique `id` attribute if it has an `id` attribute.  Then, we're searching for all of the `<option>` tags only within *that* `<select>` tag, and then we get all of the values from each `<option>`.

Answer (score 4):

Just select the `select` tag instead, then loop over the contained string elements:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("./test.html").read(),"lxml");
select = soup.find('select', id="start_dateid")
for value in select.stripped_strings:
    print value
```

It *is* a slight shortcut; you could instead loop over `select.find_all('option')` instead and get the `.text` property from each, but since no other elements are present anyway, why not go straight for the string iterable and be done with it. After all, only `<option>` and `<optgroup>` tags are permitted in a `<select>` tag, and only `<option>` tags hold text.

Output from the interactive interpreter:

```
>>> select = soup.find('select', id="start_dateid")
>>> for value in select.stripped_strings:
...     print value
... 
2002/12
2003/12
2004/12
2005/12
2006/12
2007/12
2008/12
2009/12
2010/12
2011/12
```

If you need to turn this into a list, simply use:

```
values = list(select.stripped_strings)
```

Comment: The `stripped_strings` answer can be problematic if there are non-`<option>` fields within the `<select>`--they would also come out in the `stripped_strings` iterable.  Better to specify we're looking specifically for `<option>` tags.

Comment: @jdotjdot: Only `optgroup` and `option` tags are allowed in a `select`, the only *text* you will ever find in a `select` is text within `option` tags. What other text were you expecting in a `select`?

Comment: I'm not expecting anything else in a `select`, just from years of data mining from terribly written sites, I'm guarding against invalid HTML.  Just because there _shouldn't be_ anything else in the `select` doesn't mean there won't.